# How is this MOSFET in a LTC3862-2 datasheet example only 60V? <solved, user error>

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, boost

*SOLVED* I was somehow looking at the wrong part (SI7370DP, not SI7430DP). This is sort of a useless question now.

I'm looking at the LTC3862-2 current mode step-up DC/DC controller for a 100V 1A supply solution, and I don't understand the MOSFET selection.

In this example circuit, Q1 and Q2 are Si7430DPs, which are 60V rated D-S. How is that right? I'm simulating this in LTspice, and I'm getting >107V across these FETs. Is this a mistake?

[image: LTC3862-2 page 40]

Would something like the [IPB108N15N3](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/IPP_I111N15N3+G_IPB108N15N3+G_Rev2.1.pdf?folderId=db3a304325305e6d01254a567c041b4e&fileId=db3a304325305e6d01254a5795541b4f) be a reasonable replacement?

If this was an oversight... I'm a bit nervous using this design. Does it otherwise look okay? Is there anything else here to be concerned with?

Would there be better parts to use for maximum efficiency and reliability?

*SOLVED* I was somehow looking at the wrong part (SI7370DP, not SI7430DP). This is sort of a useless question now.

Comment: It's an oversight. VDSmax for Si7430DP is 150V.

Comment: The question is factually wrong at the core... I was looking at the wrong part. Nothing to see here.

Comment: Since this was just my mistake looking at the wrong part number at 1am (which strangely I thought I double checked)... I don't see the value in this question anymore.  Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where did you find the specification for the Vds = 60V, I looked up a datasheet [for the Si7430DP](http://www.vishay.com/docs/74282/si7430dp.pdf) and it states a Vds = 150V

Comment: Wow... sorry. Apparently, I was looking at the SI7370DP. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

That is rather odd.  Yes, those transistors will see the full output voltage of the converter, so they will definitely need to be rated higher than the converter's design output voltage.  My guess is that they may have designed that circuit for a lower voltage, and then changed the component values for a higher voltage but forgot to switch out the transistors.  You should be fine with a higher voltage replacement.  Actually, the last couple of times I have built converters I used completely different components with compatible specs and I did not have any issues.